# Select in draggable popup not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, popup

I have problem with select in draggable popup, sometimes you can't choose option. I was trying everything and still I haven't found answer. On other browsers it seems working fine (Chrome/Firefox) but I have to support IE too. Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a9ntp/13/

```
var popup = $('<div>Hello world!</div>');
$(popup ).dialog({title: 'Text <select id="dropDown"><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option><option>D</option></select>', draggable: false});

$('#dropDown').hover(
    function(){
        $(popup).dialog('option', 'draggable', false);
    },
    function(){
        $(popup).dialog('option', 'draggable', true);
    }
);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of IE are you using, what version of JQuery ?

Comment: IE 8 and 9, jquery-1.8.3.js and jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js

Answer (score 0):

try this HOTFIX comming directly from Redworth (JQuery team)

```
// HOTFIX: We can't upgrade to jQuery UI 1.8.6 (yet)
// This hotfix makes older versions of jQuery UI drag-and-drop work in IE9
(function($){var a=$.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseMove;$.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseMove=function(b){if($.browser.msie&&document.documentMode>=9){b.button=1};a.apply(this,[b]);}}(jQuery));
```

Put it at the beggining of your JQuery code.